# Passing a data from a dynamic table via POST

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app. There is a table on a view and a button which allows dynamically add/remove rows from the table.

I need to pass all the values from the table via POST in the format like `params[:my_table_data]` and be able to access them like `params[:my_table_data][:total]`, `params[:my_table_data][0]`, `params[:my_table_data][0][2]`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name your inputs with a `[]` at the end, rails will collect them all in an array in your params.

eg:

```
<input name="data[]" value="one">
<input name="data[]" value="two">
```

Will produce:

```
params[:data][0] == "one"
params[:data][1] == "two"
```

I don't think you can do a `data[][]` (I haven't tried though) but you can manually add indexes:

You can keep using this syntax multiple times:

```
<input name="data[1][]" value="one">
<input name="data[1][]" value="two">
<input name="data[2][]" value="three">
<input name="data[2][]" value="four">
```

The rails form helpers will automatically do this for you, if you have a collection of checkboxes, or a multiselect, etc.

Comment: what about params[:data][0][3]? how do I get all the values from a table?